# Ansible Playbook on Jetson Xavier

Tags: python, ansible

I was trying to configure the Xavier using the Jetson Ansible Playbook. When I run

```
ansible-playbook -kK -i targets -l NVIDIA jetson_install.yml
```

I get following error:

```
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
Enter your Bitbucket username:
Enter your Bitbucket password: 

PLAY [Install NVIDIA Xavier] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xavier/.ssh/id_rsa': 
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 20.04 on host localhost should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible 
release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature 
will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Install python and aptitude] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 100, "stderr": "Shared connection to localhost closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to localhost closed."], "stdout": "\r\n\rReading package lists... 0%\r\rReading package lists... 100%\r\rReading package lists... Done\r\r\n\rBuilding dependency tree... 0%\r\rBuilding dependency tree... 0%\r\rBuilding dependency tree... 50%\r\rBuilding dependency tree... 50%\r\rBuilding dependency tree       \r\r\n\rReading state information... 0%\r\rReading state information... 0%\r\rReading state information... Done\r\r\nPackage python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.\r\nThis may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or\r\nis only available from another source\r\nHowever, the following packages replace it:\r\n  python3-pip\r\n\r\nE: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["", "", "Reading package lists... 0%", "", "Reading package lists... 100%", "", "Reading package lists... Done", "", "", "Building dependency tree... 0%", "", "Building dependency tree... 0%", "", "Building dependency tree... 50%", "", "Building dependency tree... 50%", "", "Building dependency tree       ", "", "", "Reading state information... 0%", "", "Reading state information... 0%", "", "Reading state information... Done", "", "Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.", "This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or", "is only available from another source", "However, the following packages replace it:", "  python3-pip", "", "E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate"]}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How do I solve this error?

I tried to install pip for Python 3 using the following commands. However, I still get the same problem.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: Apt developers have made great efforts to deliver meaningful and clear error messages that you should read: `Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.\r\nThis may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or\r\nis only available from another source\r\nHowever, the following packages replace it:\r\n  python3-pip`

Comment: How do I fix this error? I tried different methods to fix this issue but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you **playbook/role** install python3-pip rather than phyton-pip. This might eventually fix it. Or modify your apt source list to include one that knows python-pip. Alternatively use role/collection which does not install obsoleted packages.

Comment: I tried to install python3-pip using `sudo apt install python3-pip`, but that did not solve the issue. How do I do those checks, could you please clarify?

Comment: The issue is that your role/playbook is trying to install python-pip on a system where it is not available. Installing python3-pip yourself manually will not help. You have to change the playbook/role or add an apt source providing that missing package on the system. Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried these solutions? https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-installation-candidate-problem-ubuntu/